# CGRect unrecognized in subclasses of NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject, cgrect

Recently I noticed that I cannot use `CGRect` in any classes I've made that are subclasses of `NSObject`. I get an error: "Unknown type name 'CGRect'; did you mean 'Rect'?" If I include `<UIKit/UIKit.h>`, I am able to use `CGRect` again. However, I noticed that in the classes of my older projects, I am still able to use `CGRect` without having to import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>`. I'm curious as to why this occurs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because older projects imported UiKit.h in the precompiled prefix header (pch) file.